# The Rust Programming Language Pig Latin Exercise

Tags: rust

This is my implementation of the Pig Latin recommended exercise in The Rust Programming Language book. I am using the [unicode segmentation crate](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation) to split the string into words while also keeping the delimiters. Any pointers on making this code more idiomatic or run more optimal?

```
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

#[allow(overlapping_patterns)]
fn translate_word(s: &str) -> String {
  let mut it = s.chars();
  let first = it.next().unwrap();
  match first.to_ascii_lowercase() {
    'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' => format!("{}-hay", s),
    'a'..='z' => format!("{}-{}ay", it.collect::<String>(), first),
    _ => s.to_string(),
  }
}

pub fn translate(s: &str) -> String {
  s.split_word_bounds()
    .map(translate_word)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .join("")
}
```

The code is inside a module named `pig_latin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Be aware that Rust typically uses 4 spaces

It's fine if you consistently use 2 spaces (especially if you override it in rustfmt.toml), but just be aware that the standard is different.

### Collect directly to a `String`

Instead of collecting to a `Vec` and then copying that over to a new `Vec` (within `String`), collect to a `String` directly:

```rust
pub fn translate(s: &str) -> String {
    s.split_word_bounds().map(translate_word).collect()
}
```

### Use `Chars::as_str`

When you use `str::chars`, the specific iterator that it returns is called [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html). It has a [handy function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str) to get the remaining part, so you don't need to allocate a new string:

```rust
'a'..='z' => format!("{}-{}ay", it.as_str(), first),
```

### Use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)

This is a bit of an advanced optimization that you don't need to do—the Book doesn't even mention it once.

Currently, you allocate a new `String` even when the output is identical to the input. Instead, return `Cow<str>`: if the first character isn't a letter, you can return `Cow::Borrowed(s)`, which points to the existing `&str`. If it does start with a letter, return `Cow::Owned(format!(...))`, which has the same overhead as it did before. Here, I'm using `.into()` instead of writing `Cow::Owned` and `Cow::Borrowed` explicitly. You can do either.

```rust
fn translate_word(s: &str) -> Cow<str> {
    let mut it = s.chars();
    let first = it.next().unwrap();
    match first.to_ascii_lowercase() {
        'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' => format!("{}-hay", s).into(),
        'a'..='z' => format!("{}-{}ay", it.as_str(), first).into(),
        _ => s.into(),
    }
}
```

## Final code

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78daca7b7adab4587436cacf35bca90e